# SQL Query with count, sum and group by

Tags: sql, count, group-by

Quick question if anyone has time to answer.  The current query works great, but I need to also get a total count of the orders and the total shipping.  I know the numbers are getting thrown off because of the joins.

I know that my count and sum will be:

```
count(DISTINCT orders.id) AS num_orders,
SUM(orders.shipping_cost_ex_tax) AS shipping
```

I think I need to use the count and sum in the original select and handle the rest in the join, but for the life of me I can't get this right.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's "run a separate query".  Thanks everyone.

Current query:

```
SELECT 
    IF(products.categories LIKE '68', 'Shirts', 'Books') AS group_key,
    CONCAT(order_products.name) AS product_name,
    brands.name AS author,
    SUM(order_products.quantity) AS num_units,
    CASE WHEN products.sku LIKE '%-WB' THEN 'Combo'
        WHEN products.sku LIKE '%-BO' THEN 'Box'
        ELSE ''
    END AS item_type,
    SUM(IF(order_products.discount IS NULL, order_products.price_ex_tax, (order_products.price_ex_tax - order_products.discount))) AS income 
 FROM orders 
 INNER JOIN order_products ON order_products.bc_order_id = orders.bc_id
 INNER JOIN products ON order_products.bc_product_id = products.bc_id
 INNER JOIN brands ON products.brand_id = brands.bc_id 
 WHERE (orders.created_at BETWEEN '2012-01-28 00:00:00' and '2012-02-21 23:00:00') 
 GROUP BY group_key,
 case when products.brand_id = '68'
 then products.name
 else products.sku
 end
```

Comment: What SQL product are you using?

Comment: If the joins are throwing you off and not all the other shenanigans, I'd try reworking it with subqueries that do smaller parts of the work. Also, your `income` can be written `SUM(order_products.price_ex_tax - COALESCE(order_products.discount, 0))` and your `CONCAT(order_products.name)` is the same as just `order_products.name`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  I should have known that but didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the comment provided and not having your full schema in front of me.  Would something like this work:

```
Table Report  
(  
    id,  
    countOrders,  
    countSales,  
    countShipping,  
    countTax,  
    datePublished  
)   

Table SoldProducts  
(  
    id,  
    price,    
    tax,  
    shippingPrice,  
    datePurchased  
)
```

So what you would do in this instance is generate a report by querying from `SoldProducts` then you would persist the report that was generated.

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified that a bit.  This is an admin report to show sales for a given time period.  The first section is just the overall totals (number of orders, total sales, total shipping, total tax).  Beneath that is a breakdown by products sold, with the total sale amount and number of units per product.

Comment: @ChrisYount I have updated my reply, it may help make things easier as more of these report gets generated.